# Adjective/noun to describe a small but extremely useful thing

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an adjective/noun for a thing (e.g computer) that is small/not fully functional compared with other, similar such things, but whose performance is extremely advanced.

[Updates]

My English may not be good enough to express my idea, but I find @sameyeam's is the best fit for my unclear question.

"Pared down and **streamlined**, the thing's great performance has been unleashed by shedding features you don't need."

Also helpful:

**Streamlined emphasizes efficiency and ease of use** more than specific but powerful functionality.

I'm still looking for an noun to describe it. **Peppy** may be a fit, but I need more suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about "streamlined?"  As in, "Pared down and streamlined, the thing's great performance has been unleashed by shedding features you don't need."

Comment: *Streamlined* emphasizes efficiency and ease of use more than specific but powerful functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe "specialized" or "niche product". I also like Dror's suggestion of "peppy".

But frankly, I think you're looking for too specific a word. I'd suggest you use a phrase or sentence to explain what you mean. It's not always possible to find a single word that expresses any idea you can possibly think of.

Comment: +1 *Specialised* sounds like exactly what the OP is looking for—not powerful in general, but very good for a narrower purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Packed? Packed emphasizes its high performance to size ratio, regardless of the actual size though.

Similarly, packs a punch.

Answer (score 2):

Would *[gadget](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gadget)* or *[device](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/device)* suffice?

> **gadget**: an often small mechanical or electronic device with a practical use
>
> **device** : something fanciful, elaborate, or intricate in design

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a precise one. But "gizmo" or "widget" might work because they both mean small devices/inventions for a particular control. They are supposed to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression you want a word for a small item that is suitable only for a few special purposes, but very good at them, that is, highly capable equipment usable for a small range of purposes.  I don't know of any such word.  Figuratively, you might refer to the item as an *[idiot savant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idiot_savant)*. Also consider *[holon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holons)*, "something that is simultaneously a whole and a part." 
For neologisms, consider *supersprout, micromoonrocket, microgiant, oligobonzer* 
(*[oligo-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=oligo)*, from Gk. *oligos* "small, little," in plural, "few"; *[bonzer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bonzer)*, "remarkable; wonderful; comparative: more bonzer, superlative: most bonzer").

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is [peppy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peppy). Google peppy car to see how it's used and if it matches your need.

Comment: There's no indication of localisation in the OP, but `peppy` is almost entirely unknown in British English, and where it is used it means "whizzy; full of pep, verve, go".

Answer (score 0):

An accurate but clumsy phrase would be "something small that has a small cost and a small cost/benefit ratio". A metaphorical approach might do nicely, though: "a Swiss knife item".

Answer (score 0):

***Compact*** does a good job of expressing smaller-in-size, without necessarily an implied loss of functionality.

But, to make things perfectly clear, I'd suggest using a couple of words, to convey both concepts - something like:

- *The **compact yet powerful** XR90 router...*
- *The **scaled-down yet speedy** XR90 router...*

You could also say something like, "*The XR90 router does **more with less***."